# Text and button different font size on same line

Tags: css

I have button and text on the same line. They have different font size. Button has padding. In browser it seems that text is on the same line, but the padding goes below the big text. I want the bottom button padding be on the same line as the big text. In other words, shift text a bit down or button a bit up.

[image]

Here's my CSS

```css
.bigtext {
    font-size: 200%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

.button-container {
    display: inline-block;
}

.button-container button {
    font-size: 40%;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7ydtgb7x/

Comment: Go read up on the `vertical-align` property.

Comment: Post your HTML, or prepare a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Just give us a snippet or a fiddle example :)

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot about it. Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7ydtgb7x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a really simple way to do this you can just add "position: relative;" and "bottom: 5px;" to your button.

If you need any help let me know by adding a comment. There are three kind of positions:

Relative which follows the flow.

Absolute that almost follows the flow.

And Fixed which gets completely out of any flow.

```css
.bigtext {
    font-size: 200%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

.button-container {
    display: inline-block;
}

.button-container button {
    font-size: 40%;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigtext">
    Test
    <div class="button-container">
        <button>Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know that I can use `bottom` not in absolute positioned only.

Comment: If you need any help let me know by adding a comment. There are Relative which follows the normal flow, absolute that almost follows the flow and fixed that gets out of any flow.

Answer (score 1):

for a quick fix:

```
transform:translateY(-5px);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/7ydtgb7x/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution for you:

wrap your **Test** with a `div`, then both child's of `.bigtext` are (already) displayed `inline-block`, just make sure they are `vertical-align:top`.

Align vertical as well the button like this:

```css
.button-container button { vertical-align:top}
```

Finally "reset" the `line-height` for your container `.bigtext` with: `line-height:1`

Here is a snippet with full code:

```css
.bigtext {
  font-size: 200%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  line-height: 1
}
.bigtext > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.button-container button {
  font-size: 40%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  vertical-align: top
}
```

```html
<div class="bigtext">
  <div class="text-container">Test</div>
  <div class="button-container">
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this approach, but I'd like to have more control of the positioning of button. And the extra div forces me to work on layout for other titles which don't have this button. Well, for this time `translateY` saves my life, but probably I will turn my sight on your solution later.

Answer (score 0):

Use either `transform: translateY(-10px);` or `margin-bottom: 10px;`